Specify multiple values for one argument Python Argparser
I've built a working CLI for my app using python's argparse. It's called comicbot, and it sends emails with comics in them. The bulk subparser allows a certain number of comics to be specified.
usage: comicbot bulk [-h] [-e END | -c COUNT] email [email ...] comic start

positional arguments:
  email                 recipient email addresses
  comic                 comic on gocomics [calvin-and-hobbes]
  start                 date of first strip [YYYY-MM-DD]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -e END, --end END     date of last strip [YYYY-MM-DD]
  -c COUNT, --count COUNT
                        number of comics to include

I have three positional arguments: email, comic and date. My problem is that email accepts one or more values. How can I specify that these values belong to email, rather than the second filling the comic slot, and the third the date?
I've tried the following.
python -m comicbot bulk 123@gmail.com 456@gmail.com calvin-and-hobbes 1995-06-06 -c 5
# interprets 456@gmail.com as comic
python -m comicbot bulk {123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com} calvin-and-hobbes 1995-06-06 -c 5
# interprets email as '{123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com}'

Square brackets behave the same as {}, and () throw an error from terminal.
I am able to change the structure of my program to just accept a single argument for email and then give a string of addresses seperated by commas, but I'd rather find a solution to this.
Any suggestions? Any code changes required? Or just syntax?

It's not easy with argparse. Recommend to use options instead of positional arguments, then you can just do nargs="+".

@wim I'm already doing nargs="+", with positional. Does nargs somehow force it to become an option, even without '--email'?

Look at the sys.argv to see what the shell is doing with the brackets, paren, etc.  sys.argv will be a simple list of strings regardless of what you use.  With your argparse, 3 strings will be allocated to the 3 positionals.  With 4 strings, email gets 2, etc.  You might be happier if you define email as the last of the positionals.

When parsing strings for the positionals, each gets one, and any extras are allocated to the variable part of the + nargs. The OS shell does not pass any groupings on through to sys.argv.

Here are my suggestions

Move email to the last position
Instead of start, I prefer --start, so that it goes well with --end

The code then become:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-s", "--start", required=True, help="date of first strip [YYYY-MM-DD]"
)
parser.add_argument("-e", "--end", help="date of last strip [YYYY-MM-DD]")
parser.add_argument("-c", "--count", default=1, help="number of comics to include")
parser.add_argument("comic", help="comic on gocomics [calvin-and-hobbes]")
parser.add_argument("email", nargs="+", help="recipient email addresses")

Help output:
usage: my.py [-h] -s START [-e END] [-c COUNT] comic email [email ...]

positional arguments:
  comic                 comic on gocomics [calvin-and-hobbes]
  email                 recipient email addresses

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s START, --start START
                        date of first strip [YYYY-MM-DD]
  -e END, --end END     date of last strip [YYYY-MM-DD]
  -c COUNT, --count COUNT
                        number of comics to include

